# Programming HC05

Tags: bluetooth, sdk, hc-05

HC05 comprises of BL417 and a flash memory. I want to program BL417 to use its IO pins.

can you help me with the BC417 coding. I read its datasheet and found that I can get the software from http://dev.protonbasic.co.uk/Crownhill%20QuickBlue/bluetooth_project/bluecore/CSR%20Support%20-%20BlueLab%20SDK.htm here but when I tried it wanted to create an account on qualcomm. and when I created it said 404 error.

So basically right now I need Bluelab SDK to program the BC417 of HC05.
Also if you have done any coding with that in past please share the sample code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did You try something?

Comment: after getting that  404 error. I asked qualcomm and wrote for access to Blue lab SDK but then they emailed back that all the data is not accessible to public. If you are a entity working with Qualcomm then write us back and we will verify and give that.  How do I program without Blue lab SDK I am trying to search for alternatives..

Comment: I still dont understand, that they are selling the chip, and in the datasheet they have mentioned that you can make customized applications (and given numerous examples as well) using the Bluelab SDK and then they are not giving the SDK ..

Comment: Is there any other way, or somebody has done it.. or is there any alternative to this chip for which the respective SDK is also available .. Thanks in advance